# CMake: How to add a custom variable for user macro with a value that depends on build configuration?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I use CMake version 3.16.

I tried the following:

```
set_property(TARGET ${PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTY VS_GLOBAL_FR_VERSION 
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug2017>:"2017">
    $<$<CONFIG:Release2017>:"2017">
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug2018>:"2018">
    $<$<CONFIG:Release2018>:"2018">
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug2019>:"2019">
    $<$<CONFIG:Release2019>:"2019">
)
```

And it kind of worked...

This variable `(FR_VERSION)` is supposed to be used in a script that is launched after build. This is how it looks:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PLUGIN_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND echo $(FR_VERSION)
    COMMENT "This command will copy files to dist"
    VERBATIM
)
```

In Visual Studio, however, we got the following:

```
echo $<$<CONFIG:Debug2017>:"2017">;$<$<CONFIG:Release2017>:"2017">;$<$<CONFIG:Debug2018>:"2018">;$<$<CONFIG:Release2018>:"2018">;$<$<CONFIG:Debug2019>:"2019">;$<$<CONFIG:Release2019>:"2019">
```

which fails to execute with the error message:

```
"The syntax of the command is incorrect."
```

If I don't try to set a different value for different build configs like this:

```
set_target_properties(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_FR_MAYA_VERSION "2018")
```

then the post-build script is generated as expected. (But this is not acceptable to me, because I need different parameter values for different build configurations).

I would appreciate any advice at this point.

Comment: Did you try using the generator expression instead of `$()`? Or using `${}` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some target properties support generator expressions, while others do not. The documentation for a property will **explicitly** say that generator expressions are supported. Take the [`COMPILE_FEATURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_FEATURES.html) property, for example:

> Contents of `COMPILE_FEATURES` may use “generator expressions” with the syntax `$<...>`.

The documentation for [`VS_GLOBAL_<variable>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_GLOBAL_variable.html) does not have such language. Thus, as suggested, you can put the generator expression directly in the `add_custom_command()` call, which is supported:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PLUGIN_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND echo $<$<CONFIG:Debug2017>:"2017">
        $<$<CONFIG:Release2017>:"2017">
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug2018>:"2018">
        $<$<CONFIG:Release2018>:"2018">
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug2019>:"2019">
        $<$<CONFIG:Release2019>:"2019">
    COMMENT "This command will copy files to dist"
)
```

Comment: Yes, this worked, thanks! Need to remove VERBATIM flag though

Comment: @DmitriiMotorygin Glad it's working! Fixed the answer to remove that flag. Thanks!